# How can I calculate $\int \frac{\sec x\tan x}{3x+5}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

How can I calculate
$$
\int{\sec\left(x\right)\tan\left(x\right)  \over 3x + 5}\,{\rm d}x
$$

My Try:: $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{3x+5}\left(\sec x\tan x \right)\,\mathrm dx$

Now Using Integration by Parts::

We Get $\displaystyle  = \frac{1}{3x+5}\sec x +\int  \frac{3}{(3x+5)^2}\sec x\,\mathrm  dx$

Now My Question is How Can I calculate (II) Integral.

Please explain this to me.

Comment: In mathematics, it is not necessary to use a dot `.` to indicate product; if you really want an explicit indication of it, then the TeX command `\cdot` will provide you with a centred dot: $\cdot$.

Comment: Mathematica refuses symbolic integration. Did the original problem include bounds on your integral (making it a definite integral instead of an indefinite one)?

Comment: I don't think that's going to come out to be doable with elementary functions with that linear term in the denominator and something trigonometric in the numerator.  Also, I think your derivative is slightly off.

Comment: I agree with Mike. No this is not going to be able to...it seems that you will have infinite terms integrating symbolically

Comment: If you convert the secant into a power series, then you may be able to write an expression for the integral.

Comment: Too much computation time on Wolfram. Guessing it's not really possible or REALLY long.

Comment: This has no closed form solution according to [integrals.wolfram](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28sec[x]%29%2F%28%283x%2B5%29^2%29)

Comment: @juantheron May I ask the source of this problem pelase?

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618317/so-close-yet-so-far-finding-int-frac-sec-x-tan-x3x5-dx?lq=1).